# Uploading the APK fails even after incrementing the version code?

Tags: android

I am currently trying to upload an update for my app on the Play Store. I've updated it a number of times and am trying to put out another one using the exact same steps I always have.

Here is the upload error I am getting on the Play Console page:

```
Upload failed
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 13.
```

Ok, so thats an easy fix. I must have forgot to bump up the version code. But looking at the gradle I definitely did increment it. The gradle version code was moved up to 14.

I then just decided to try again so I increased the version code again (it is now 15) and the version name up again. The newly signed apk is also giving the same message.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Try invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its OK it happens sometimes with android studio , what you need to do is:

- Clean your android project (Run -> Clean project)
- Delete Debug `(output -> apk -> ___.apk)` and release `(app -> ___.apk)` files
- Create Signed build again , possibly by incrementing the version code again in build.gradle and rechecking your .jks file
- Now Upload that release apk to PlayStore Console.